# VBA pulling from website

Tags: excel, vba, html

The code I'm using it quite extensive, so I would rather not post it unless need be. I'm creating an obj request using MSXML2.XMLHTTP to recieve an HTML response. I'm then parsing it into columns. My issue is that the initial run, from startup of excel, it does about 5 per second. If I try to run it after the initial run it does about 50 a second. I want each pull to be fresh, but it seems it's storing the response somewhere for the speed to be that fast. If I restart excel the initial pull is reset to the same speed. Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the request URL and method (get or post)? Better to post a snippet of the code. Anything that helps to reproduce request. Generally the issue you described caused by XHR requests caching, and can be solved by sending no-cache header, or by using ServerXMLHTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it seems it was defaulting to the IE caching options. Once I set IE to check for a new version of the web page each time it worked correctly. When changing this option through IE it solved the issue. XMLHTTP would not work my method, or rather the website I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to find the answer to this, the issue is the request is using IE caching options. If you set IE to check for a new webpage each time, the code will also check each time.